# Automating uploading files via asking filepath from user in python

Tags: python, json, excel, csv

```
# This module takes path of any random dataset from the user

class User_Input():
  # Taking File Path as input from the user
  user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")

  # The assert keyword lets you test if a condition in your code returns True, if not, the program will raise an AssertionError.
  assert os.path.exists(user_input), " did not find the file at, "+str(user_input)
  user_file = open(user_input,'r+')

  print(" found the file !")

  for fp in user_file:
      # Split the extension from the path and normalise it to lowercase.
      ext = os.path.splitext(fp)[-1].lower().suffix()

      # For handling breakdown in case of any errors
      try:
        # Now we can simply use .endswith to check for equality, no need for wildcards.
        # For handling csv files
        if ext.endswith('.csv'):
            df = pd.read_csv(user_input)

        # For handling excel files
        elif ext.endswith('.xlsx'):
            df = pd.read_excel(user_input)

        # For handling json files
        elif ext.endswith('.json'):
            df = pd.read_json(user_input)

        # For handing unknown files types
        else:
            print( fp,"is an unknown file format.")
            break

      # to handle the situation if try block gets failed
      except:
          pass

  user_file.close()
```

I am trying to automate uploading any file extension(like- .csv, .json, .xlsx etc) and read the code in dataframe. But , this shows assertion error, but I am providing the right path? Also there is some problem with the encoding!

It must not break and tell the user about any errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Assertion error is raised by your `assert` statement, which is outside the `try` block so the error raised is not caught by the `except` statement.

A better alternative may be to remove the assert altogether and open the file within the `try` block:

```py
try:
    with open(user_input, "r+") as file:
           # process file contents
except:
    pass
```

If the path is invalid, a `FileNotFound` error will be raised safely in the `try` block.

Comment: You mean, I have to use one more try block before assertion.

Comment: There's no reason to do so. You can move the try block around the open statement.